# Не получается прикрепить файл к форме

Tags: javascript, html

Всем доброй ночи. Есть такой инпут:

```
<input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/*">
```

И такой обработчик:

```
$('input[name="avatar"]').change(function(event) {

    form = new FormData();
    form.append('avatar', $(this).files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/account/avatar',
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data: form ,
        success: function(response){
            alert(response.message);
        }
    })
});
```

Здесь:

> form.append('avatar', $(this).files[0]);

вылазит ошибка:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Как правильно прикрепить файл ? p.s. в консоль: `console.log($(this))` выводится нормальный объект. Благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Отладчик для чего нужен? Подсказка: доллар лишний.

Comment: @Qwertiy тоже рабочий вариант. Через отладчик и смотрел как раз.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `event.target.files[0]` вместо `$(this).files[0]`

Comment: contentType: 'multipart/form-data' добавьте в опции при вызове $.ajax